# <Routes> won't render component that behave as an container of many <Route>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I get this warning when I wrapped my component in `<Routes>`.

> Warning: [Categories] is not a `<Route>` component. All component
> children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

App.js

```
const App = () => {
   return (
        <div className="app__container">
            <Header />
            <Nav />
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    {/* This two component get warning */}
                    <Categories />
                    <Details />      
                </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Categories.js

```
const Categories = () => {
  return (
    <>    
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/movie" />} />    

        <Route path="/movie" element={<Movies /> } />
        <Route path="/tv" element={<Tv />}/>
        <Route path="/person" element={<People />} />
        <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Details.js

```
const Details = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <Route path="/movie/:tmdbID" element={<MovieDetail />}/>
        <Route path="/tv/:tmdbID" element={<TvDetail />}/>
        <Route path="/person/:tmdbID" element={<PersonDetail/>}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

As you can see, it seems like `<Routes>` won't take just `Categories` and `Details` as a children.

I'm doing it because I want the `Route` to be placed in different folder/file. Which in `Categories.js` and `Details.js`

So, how can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Routes` component can only have `Route` or `React.Fragment` as valid children. Neither `Categories` or `Details` can be rendered directly by `Routes` like this.

Render all the routes together as in the following:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app__container">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/movie" />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />

          <Route path="/movie">
            <Route index element={<Movies /> } />
            <Route path=":tmdbID" element={<MovieDetail />} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/tv">
            <Route index element={<Tv />} />
            <Route path=":tmdbID" element={<TvDetail />} />
          </Route>

          <Route path="/person">
            <Route index element={<People />} />
            <Route path=":tmdbID" element={<PersonDetail/>} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This organization uses *nested* routes.

Or if you are trying to code-split you can split the routes logically by routes/sub-routes where components render *descendent* routes. In order for descendent routes to work the parent route path appends a wildcard matcher, or splat, `"*"` to its path and the routed component renders another `Routes` and set of `Route` components.

```
const MovieRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Movies /> } />
    <Route path="/:tmdbID" element={<MovieDetail />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const TvRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Tv />} />
    <Route path="/:tmdbID" element={<TvDetail />} />
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const PersonRoutes = () => (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<People />} />
    <Route path="/:tmdbID" element={<PersonDetail/>} />
  </Routes>
);
```

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app__container">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Nav />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/movie" />} />
          <Route path="/search" element={<Search />} />

          <Route path="/movie/*" element={<MovieRoutes />} />
          <Route path="/tv/*" element={<TvRoutes />} />
          <Route path="/person/*" element={<PersonRoutes />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is accurate.  `Categories` and `Details` are not `<Route>` values, the are their own component values.  The fact that they have `<Route>` elements within their JSX does not make them `<Route>` elements.

If this is a new project, you might consider going with React-Router newer [createBrowserRouter()](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) construct where you define routes as data (an array of JS objects) rather than as JSX elements.  Then you could define Categories and Details as data and reference that data anywhere in your code.

Use of `createBrowserRouter()` is the recommended way forward for people using React-Router.

Comment: Thank you. But do you think there's another solution by only modify my code?

Comment: The children of `<Routes>` must be `<Route>` components.  https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes